# How to draw round segment

Tags: graphics

I'd like to draw a round segment, but dont know how.

Can you help me to draw something like this?
[image]

Comment: Using what package? pstricks? tikz?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Using package tikz.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: God bless Ignasi :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one possibility to do something similar to what you want

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) coordinate[label=above:A](a) -- ++(3,0) coordinate [label=above:B](b);
\draw (b) to[out=110,in=70] ++(-2,0) node[below] (d) {D};
\draw ([xshift=-1cm]b) to[out=-70,in=-110] ++(2,0) node[above] (c) {C}--++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]